# Trying to import HTML from a helper, but Rails isn't loving it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I basically have a form that submits a remote GET request, which then displays a modal. I have several different actions that can use the same model, so I'm simply trying to use a helper and jQuery to display different data, depending on what's showing.

Here's what I'm dealing with. This is my add_users.js.erb file (what gets called after the remote GET request):

```
$('.modal-footer').html("<%= import_users_html %>");
```

Here's what the helper looks like:

```
def import_users_html
    html = link_to '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Import Users'.html_safe, '#', remote: :true, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm"
    return html
end
```

However, when it returns HTML, it doesn't display in the `<div class="modal-footer"` section.If I replace that `import_users_html` with "Hello World", then it works perfectly.

Somewhere, it's not liking the results of html. Here's what the variable `html` actually is before it is returned to the `add_users.js.erb` view:

```
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f3bbe257050>>)> puts html
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-remote="true" href="#"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Import Users</a>
```

I've tried random things like `html_safe`, `raw`, and none of it seems to work for some strange reason.

** EDIT **

So I figured out it's because `link_to` ends up converting the link to include double quotes, which is what I'm using in my `add_users.js.erb` helper, so I guess it's conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript code try something like:

```
$('.modal-footer').html("<%= j(import_users_html) %>");
```

`j` is an alias to `escape_javascript` which will take care of your quotes conflicts.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.